# How to obtain a disk's parent value using powershell

Tags: powershell, storage

I am trying to access the properties of a disk and specifically looking for its parent value as shown in the screenshot below:
[Disk properties as seen by right clicking on a disk and trying to fetch the parent value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blDyV.png)

I am not able to obtain the correct commandlet to obtain the information. I have tried the following command from: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/feb9341a-fd0a-47af-adff-e3ae33071a22

I have also tried" Get-Disks and that did not help me get what I want. Was wondering if there is a powershell command that can let the user obtain the parent value of a Disk?

Would appreciate any help here.

Thanks,
Kaushik Prakash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Script to retrieve the value :

```
$disk = (gwmi win32_DiskDrive -Property * | ?{$_.PnpDeviceID -eq 'SCSI\DISK&VEN_SAMSUNG&PROD_SSD_850_EVO_1TB\4&3BDA36C&0&010000'})
$PnpEntity = gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($Disk.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_PnpEntity"
switch ($Disk.InterfaceType)
{
    'IDE' 
    {
        $parentID = (gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($PnpEntity.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_IDEController").PnpDeviceID
        break; 
    }


    'SCSI' 
    {
        $parentID = (gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($PnpEntity.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_SCSIController").PnpDeviceID
        break;
    }

    'USB' 
    {
        $parentID = (gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($PnpEntity.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_USBController").PnpDeviceID
        break;
    }

    Default {}
}


Write-host $parentID
```

Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well as you can use the win32_logicaldisk class for getting the info:

```
$Items = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_DiskDrive" -namespace "root\CIMV2"

foreach ($Item in $Items) { 
      write-host "Availability: " $Item.Availability 
      write-host "Bytes Per Sector: " $Item.BytesPerSector 
      write-host "Capabilities: " $Item.Capabilities 
      write-host "Capability Descriptions: " $Item.CapabilityDescriptions 
      write-host "Caption: " $Item.Caption 
      write-host "Compression Method: " $Item.CompressionMethod 
      write-host "Configuration Manager Error Code: " $Item.ConfigManagerErrorCode 
      write-host "Configuration Manager User Configuration: " $Item.ConfigManagerUserConfig 
      write-host "Creation Class Name: " $Item.CreationClassName 
      write-host "Default Block Size: " $Item.DefaultBlockSize 
      write-host "Description: " $Item.Description 
      write-host "Device ID: " $Item.DeviceID 
      write-host "Error Cleared: " $Item.ErrorCleared 
      write-host "Error Description: " $Item.ErrorDescription 
      write-host "Error Methodology: " $Item.ErrorMethodology 
      write-host "Index: " $Item.Index 
      write-host "Installation Date: " $Item.InstallDate 
      write-host "Interface Type: " $Item.InterfaceType 
      write-host "Last Error Code: " $Item.LastErrorCode 
      write-host "Manufacturer: " $Item.Manufacturer 
      write-host "Maximum Block Size: " $Item.MaxBlockSize 
      write-host "Maximum Media Size: " $Item.MaxMediaSize 
      write-host "Media Loaded: " $Item.MediaLoaded 
      write-host "Media Type: " $Item.MediaType 
      write-host "Minimum Block Size: " $Item.MinBlockSize 
      write-host "Model: " $Item.Model 
      write-host "Name: " $Item.Name 
      write-host "Needs Cleaning: " $Item.NeedsCleaning 
      write-host "Number Of Media Supported: " $Item.NumberOfMediaSupported 
      write-host "Partitions: " $Item.Partitions 
      write-host "PNP Device ID: " $Item.PNPDeviceID 
      write-host "Power Management Capabilities: " $Item.PowerManagementCapabilities 
      write-host "Power Management Supported: " $Item.PowerManagementSupported 
      write-host "SCSI Bus: " $Item.SCSIBus 
      write-host "SCSI Logical Unit: " $Item.SCSILogicalUnit 
      write-host "SCSI Port: " $Item.SCSIPort 
      write-host "SCSI Target ID: " $Item.SCSITargetId 
      write-host "Sectors Per Track: " $Item.SectorsPerTrack 
      write-host "Signature: " $Item.Signature 
      write-host "Size: " $Item.Size 
      write-host "Status: " $Item.Status 
      write-host "Status Information: " $Item.StatusInfo 
      write-host "System Creation Class Name: " $Item.SystemCreationClassName 
      write-host "System Name: " $Item.SystemName 
      write-host "Total Cylinders: " $Item.TotalCylinders 
      write-host "Total Heads: " $Item.TotalHeads 
      write-host "Total Sectors: " $Item.TotalSectors 
      write-host "Total Tracks: " $Item.TotalTracks 
      write-host "Tracks Per Cylinder: " $Item.TracksPerCylinder 
      write-host 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Regis! That was exactly what I wanted.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $disk = (gwmi win32_DiskDrive -Property * | ?{$_.PnpDeviceID -eq 'SCSI\DISK&VEN_SANBLAZE&PROD_VLUN_P2T0L3\5&9BA739C&0&000503'})
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $PnpEntity = gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($Disk.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_PnpEntity"
PS C:\Users\Administrator> switch ($Disk.InterfaceType)
>> {
>>     'IDE'
>>     {
>>         $parentID = (gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($PnpEntity.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_IDEController").PnpDeviceID
>>         break;
>>     }
>>
>>
>>     'SCSI'
>>     {
>>         $parentID = (gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($PnpEntity.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_SCSIController").PnpDeviceID
>>         break;
>>     }
>>
>>     'USB'
>>     {
>>         $parentID = (gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($PnpEntity.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_USBController").PnpDeviceID
>>         break;
>>     }
>>
>>     Default {}
>> }
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Write-host $parentID
PCI\VEN_10DF&DEV_E300&SUBSYS_E30010DF&REV_01\4&29553A89&0&0108
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

This matches on of my Host Initiators:

```
PCI\VEN_10DF&DEV_E300&SUBSYS_E30010DF&REV_01\4&29553a89&0&0108_0 200000109b17402c 100000109b17402c Fibre Channel
```

Comment: You're Welcome ;-)